# Grouped Taxonomy Menu

Tags: drupal, menu, taxonomy

This seams like it should be very easy, but I cannot find a solution to this.

I have a content type of Training, of which there is a taxonomy reference field to mark different training courses as "Health and Safety", "First Aid" etc.

What I am trying to achieve is a menu in the sidebar that lists links to the Training nodes sorted by the Taxonomy term:

Title - Health and Safety Courses (not a link)

- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 3
- "Lots of Links"

Title - First Aid Courses (not a link)

- Node 4
- Node 5
- "Lots of Links"

Title - Business (link!)

- Node 6

The only catch is as there will be a fair amount of links, so I need to be able to collapse these links probably in an accordion, which rules out menu_views and accordion_menu as they are not compatible.

So this list of links need to be displayed as a simple

setup

(The use of Taxonomy to mark the course types can be changed for something else if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

By using views:

1. Add relationship to your taxonomy;
2. Add the Term name field (indicate relationship to taxonomy);
3. Group the results by Term name field.